# Tomcat: Unable to make HTTPS site

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tls1.2

I am trying to make intranet portal into secure(https). I have added the certificate, key Store and port redirection. Here is the tomcat server.xml config entry.

**Tomcat Server.xml Entry**

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
                port="443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
                keystoreFile="conf/certificates.jks" keystorePass="testpassword"
                clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
                sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1" />
```

**Problem Faced:**

**Google Chrome Browser**

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

XXXXXXXX.XXXXXX.com uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

I am clueless to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is that you've got your config from some old source and it is not considered safe anymore because of various attacks on SSL/TLS found over the years. See [POODLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) and [WeakDH](https://weakdh.org) for some examples. (Particularly TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA in your list is not considered safe now but probably there are much more.) Please try stronger configuration from the [OWASP wiki Tomcat page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat#Sample_Configuration_-_Good_Security) or from the [WeakDH sysadmin reference page](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html#tomcat)

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try

Comment: @y_r_k, please let us know if this helped so others can rely on this information as well.

Comment: My apologies. I did not try yet. Sure. I will give a try at the earliest.

Comment: This answer is not working